# Can't access site using mobile phone over wifi in WAMP

Tags: wireless-networking, apache-http-server, remote-access

I have a WAMP server on my local desktop office work computer, and I can access everything on it from itself with no problems. However, if I connect it to the office wifi and try to access it on a mobile phone, I get this in the apache log:

```
client denied by server configuration
```

The browser shows "Forbidden you don't have permission to access / on this server".

I get both of the errors above no matter what file or folder I try to access.

It's using apache 2.4.37.

My hosts file contains this:

```
127.0.0.1 test_folder
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test_folder

    DocumentRoot C:\wamp64\www\test_folder
    <Directory c:\wamp64\www\test_folder>
        #Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php



        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the httpd.conf contains:

```
Listen 192.168.215.197:80
```

There was an .htaccess file in the test_folder folder, but I removed it and restarted to eliminate that as a potential block.

I can't figure out why apache is blocking access over wifi.

Comment: Try just `Listen 80` rather than `Listen 192.168.215.197:80`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the <Directory /> to:

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   #Require all denied
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in

```
httpd.conf
```